# Influence of "explicit" constructors in overload resolution

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, overload-resolution

why does the following code not compile, and when I remove the explicit Keyword before the constructor in class A, it compiles?

Using Visual Studio 2013:

```
enum E { e1_0, e1_1 };

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    A() {}
    explicit A(unsigned long) {}
    A(T) {}
};

struct B
{
    B() {}
    B(E) {}
};


void F(B) {};
void F(A<short>) {};

void test()
{
    F(e1_0);
}
```

Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: exp_construct_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  exp_construct_test.cpp
1>e:\exp_construct_test\exp_construct_test.cpp(23): error C2668: 'F' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          e:\exp_construct_test\exp_construct_test.cpp(19): could be 'void F(A<short>)'
1>          e:\exp_construct_test\exp_construct_test.cpp(18): or       'void F(B)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(E)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Edit:** I downloaded clang and compiled with clang-cl which reports the error for both cases. So as has been pointed out in commentaries, the ambiguouity is between `A<short>(short)` and `B(E)`.

So perhaps there is a bug in VC++, that when I remove `explicit` from `A(unsigned long)`, the compiler by whatever intention chooses B(E) instead to raise an ambiguouity error. Can anyone confirm the clang behavior as standard compliant, and VC++ as buggy?

I added

```
void G(E) {};
void G(short) {};
```

and a call to G like this:

```
G(e1_0);
```

Which doesn't raise any error.
Why here `G(E)` is prefferred, and in case of candidates `A<short>::A(short)` and `B::B(E)`, they are ambiguous?

**End Edit**

Thanks
--joja

Comment: If I remove the `explicit`, it doesn't compile either, which also it shouldn't.  The ambiguous call is not to `A::A` but to `F`.  Note that `A::A(T)` is not `explicit` thus the call to `F` is ambiguous.  If you *add*  an `explicit` to `A::A(T)` it will rule that conversion out and the code will compile, though.

Comment: The explicit keyword in front of a constructor prevents an object of that type from being instantiated implicitly with only a parameter that would act as a constructor argument. When you remove 'explicit' from A's constructor, you can construct A simply by passing 'void F(A<short>)' a short, which is what F(e1_0) seems to be doing

Comment: @5gon12eder, which compiler are you using? In VS2013 it compiles without `explicit`. I know, that the ambiguous call is to `F`, but the cause is the conversion of `e1_0` to a type that an overload of `F` accepts. When `explicit` is removed, the compiler chooses `B(E)` to do the conversion and calls `F(B)`. I added `explicit` to be sure, that I do not implicitly use the constructor, which is a special case only constructor in my real code. In my opinion, using `explicit` should even more guide the compiler to use B(E) conversion and not consider a `enum E` to `unsigned long` promotion.

Comment: don't want no `<short>(short)` `A`

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the various variations of your example one after the other.

1. The original example calling `f(e0)`.

   ```
   enum E {e0, e1};

   template<typename T>
   struct A
   {
     A();  // (1)
     explicit A(unsigned long);  // (2)
     A(T);  // (3)
   };

   struct B
   {
     B();  // (4)
     B(E);  // (5)
   };

   void f(A<short>);  // (6)
   void f(B);  // (7)

   void g(E);  // (8)
   void g(short);  // (9)
   ```

   Among the three possibilities

   - convert `e0` to an `unsigned long`, create an `A<short>` from it via constructor (2) and call overload (6),
   - convert `e0` to `short`, create an `A<hort>` from it via constructor (3) and call overload (6) and
   - create a `B` from `e0` via constructor (5) and call overload (7)

   the first option is not applicable because (2) is `explicit`.  The remaining two both involve a user-defined conversion which are considered equally good and none is taken in favor of the other.  The call is ambiguous and the program ill-formed.
2. Let's remove the `explicit` from the constructor and call `f(e0)`.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   struct A
   {
     A();  // (1)
     A(unsigned long);  // (2)
     A(T);  // (3)
   };

   struct B
   {
     B();  // (4)
     B(E);  // (5)
   };
   ```

   The three options remain the same but this time, all three are applicable and the call is (even more) ambiguous and the program ill-formed.
3. Let's make both constructors `explicit` and call `f(e0)`.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   struct A
   {
     A();  // (1)
     explicit A(unsigned long);  // (2)
     explicit A(T);  // (3)
   };

   struct B
   {
     B();  // (4)
     B(E);  // (5)
   };
   ```

   This makes it impossible to implicitly construct an `A<short>` and the call unambiguously refers to overload (5).
4. Let's make `B`'s constructor `explicit` too and call `f(e0)`.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   struct A
   {
     A();  // (1)
     explicit A(unsigned long);  // (2)
     explicit A(T);  // (3)
   };

   struct B
   {
     B();  // (4)
     explicit B(E);  // (5)
   };
   ```

   This time, *none* of the three conversion paths is applicable because each one would go through an `explicit` constructor.  There is no overload of `f` that is applicable and the program is ill-formed.
5. Call `g(e0)`.

   We have two possibilities here:

   - Call overload (8) without any conversion or
   - convert `e0` to a `short` and call overload (9).

   Among these two, the first option in clearly favorable because it does not involve a conversion.  The call is unambiguous.  (Even if constructor (5) is not `explicit`.)

Note that the default constructors (1) and (4) actually don't contribute anything to this discussion.  Testing with GCC 4.9.1, all five examples behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @5gon12eder, for this answer. I have some remarks:

- Point 2.: with constructor (2) **not** marked explicit, neither in VisualC, nor clang I get three possible overloads reported.

- Point 1.: With (2) explicit, calling f(e0) I expected (5) to be called because only user defined constructor conversion, E -> B(E) is used, for (3) is needed one more step: E -> short -> A<short>(short).

- So you confirm, Visual C++ is buggy when it compiles example of point 2. without raising any error message and silently calling B(E)?

Comment: @joja **ad point 1:** This might seem intuitive to you but as far as I can tell, there is not rule in the standard that ranks any of these conversion sequences better than the other so the call is ambiguous.  **ad point 2:** I will not rush into claiming that a compiler I have not access to has a bug but I am rather confident that my reasoning and GCC's behavior is correct here.  Maybe a more advanced language lawyer will come by and comment with more authority on this issue.